# Scala Traits and Inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I have my Scala classes structured as below:

```
trait ActualClass extends ParentClass {
  override def method1(inputStr:String):String = {
    "actual "+ inputStr
  }
  def execute():String = {
    this.method1("test")
  }
}

trait WithClass extends ParentClass {
  override def method1(inputStr:String):String = {
    "with "+ inputStr
  }
}

class ParentClass {
  def method1(inputStr:String):String = {
    "parent "+ inputStr
  }
}

object TestClass extends App{
  val actualClass = new ActualClass with WithClass {
  }
  println(actualClass.execute())
}
```

Observed Behavior:

1. Using this.method1 in ActualClass execute method: prints "With Test"
2. Using super.method1 in ActualClass execute method: prints "parent Test"

Expected Behavior:
I need it to print: "Actual Test"

So how can I invoke the method1 that is within the ActualClass and not from WithClass or ParentClass. Is there a specific keyword for it.

Comment: The whole idea of `new ActualClass with WithClass` is that **WithClass** overrides common definitions of **ActualClass**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call specifically `ActualClass#method1` within `ActualClass`.

If you want result `"actual test"` you should define `val actualClass` vice versa

```
val actualClass = new WithClass with ActualClass
```

(method implementation is selected according to linearization order).

Generally you can't call specifically `SomeClass#someMethod` within `SomeClass` with `this.someMethod`. Implementation can always be overriden in an inheritor (unless the method is final). If you could this would be against OOP principles. You can't control `this` in such way. So `X=ActualClass` being the same in `X#method1` and `X#execute` is irrelevant in this sense.

That's why there is syntax `super[A].someMethod` (in order not to rely on linearization) but not `this[A].someMethod`.

You can try also

```
trait ActualClass extends ParentClass {
  override def method1(inputStr:String):String = {
    "actual "+ inputStr
  }
  def execute():String = {
    (new ActualClass {}).method1("test")
  }
}
```