# Incompatible type error when overriding type bounds

Tags: scala, overriding, type-alias, path-dependent-type

Can't figure out why scalac is unhappy here (2.12):

```scala
trait A {
  type Self <: A
  type X <: Self
}

trait B extends A {
  override type Self <: B
  override type X = C // error: overriding type X in trait A with bounds <: B.this.Self
}

trait C extends B {
  override type Self = C
}
```

Feels like it is because of the path-dependent types, but I don't understand what exactly is wrong and if there's a good way to fix it.

Comment: What is exactly your use case, what is your meta problem? Maybe there is another way to model it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C` is a subtype of `B`, `B` is a subtype of `A`, so `C` is a subtype of `A` but `C` is not a subtype of `A`'s `Self` or `B`'s `Self`. So you can't override (in `B`) `A`'s `X` having upper bound `Self` (i.e. `A`'s `Self`) with `C` not satisfying the bound (i.e. `B`'s `Self`).

```
trait A {
  type Self <: A
  type X <: Self

  // implicitly[C <:< Self] // doesn't compile
}

trait B extends A {
  override type Self <: B
  // override type X = C 

  // implicitly[C <:< Self] // doesn't compile
}

trait C extends B {
  override type Self = C
}
```

`C`'s `Self` equals `C` but this doesn't mean that `A`'s `Self` or `B`'s `Self` does.

You can fix compilation with lower bound

```
trait A {
  type Self <: A
  type X <: Self
}

trait B extends A {
  override type Self >: C <: B // >: C is added
  override type X = C 
}

trait C extends B {
  override type Self = C
}
```

Or if you mean that `A`'s `X` is a subtype of not `A`'s `Self` but `C`'s `Self` you can specify this with type projection

```
trait A {
  type Self <: A
  type X <: C#Self // here
}

trait B extends A {
  override type Self <: B
  override type X = C
}

trait C extends B {
  override type Self = C
}
```

I guess misunderstanding was because for `def`s

```
trait A {
  def foo(): String = "A#foo()"
  def bar(): String = s"bar=A#bar(), foo=${foo()}"
}

trait B extends A {
  def foo(): String = "A#foo()"
}

trait C extends B {
  override def foo(): String = "C#foo()"
}
```

when we write `foo()` inside `A`'s `bar()` we refer actually not to `A`'s `foo()` but to implementation's `foo()`. This is possible because method implementations are resolved late, at runtime. But types are resolved early, at compile time. So when you write

```
trait A {
  type Self <: A
  type X <: Self
}
```

`Self` in the upper bound of `X` is `A`'s `Self`, not implementation's `Self`.

OOP principles say that inside `A` you [can't refer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024762/scala-traits-and-inheritance) to `C`'s `foo()` (unless you instantiate `C`). But you can everywhere refer specifically to `A`'s `Self`, `B`'s `Self`, `C`'s `Self` with type projections `A#Self`, `B#Self`, `C#Self`.

Answer (score 3):

As a slightly different angle to Dmytro Mitin's answer: if your definition of `B` were legal, it could be further extended

```
trait D extends B {
  override type Self = D  // satisfies Self <: B
}
```

But then `X <: Self` wouldn't hold (`X` is still `C`, inherited from `B`).

Speaking more generally, constraints in `B` should imply constraints in `A`, and they don't; adding the `>: C` lower bound fixes this.